# convert time series data set to supervised for deep learining

Tags: dataset

I have dataset like [image: dataset]

so I want to use that for prediction of time series with deep learning.
I have this function to make it supervised

```
def to_supervised(train,n_input,n_out):
#falten data
data=train
X,y=list(),list()
in_start=0
for _ in range(len(data)):
    in_end=in_start+ n_input
    out_end=in_end + n_out
    if out_end<=len(data):
        x_input=data[ in_start:in_end,0]
        x_input=x_input.reshape((len(x_input)))
        X.append(x_input)
        y.append(data[in_end:out_end,0])
    in_start+=1
return array(X), array(y)
```

I am not sure about functionality of this function. Do you have replacemment for this function?

Comment: What's your objective with such a dataset ? Do you want to predict the next issued (for date 2017-01-07) ? Do you want to predict any issued according to the previous issues ?

Comment: Please copy paste code and apply the option {}, instead of using images.

Comment: @Adept: The second one is my objective .

Comment: @NicolasMartin : I am new, so thank you for telling me that I will do that in future.

Comment: You're welcome: don't forget to remove the pictures, even the table. Codes and tables are usually in text format in order to ease the search requests for other users that could have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to our comments, your objective is to "predict any issued according to the previous issues"

The best way to include time series data in such a dataset is to include variable crawling through the past dates.

For example :

- Value of the latest known records
- Value of the 7 latest known records
- Variance of the 7 latest known records
- Min, Max, etc

Example : If you want to predict in 2022-06-01, you only know data before this date, so creating variables taking past information like that can be a good idea. The biggest problem will be adapting your period to your problem (is there any gain in information if you look a few years before ?) and to handle your first cases (what do you put in the variable "Value of the 7 latest known 'issues'" if you only know 2 past records for example).